# deleteing the last four characters of a name with bash

Tags: bash, filenames

I have a directory full of files, all of them ending with the extensions filename*.gz.
The star is really a star and not a place holder. I generated these names wrongly and there are not really zipped with gz.
How can I delete the last four character including the star with bash ?

Answer (score 4):

```
for f in *'*.gz'
do
  mv "$f" "${f%?.gz}"
done
```